# Using language to correctly describe the relationship between probability increases/decreases and odds.

Tags: probability

In almost every instance of my life, when someone has referred to an increase in probability in terms of odds, they say the odds just got a lot better (odds increased, improved, etc.). When I first learned about probability and odds I immediately thought this was a language error that stemmed from the misunderstanding of the differences between probability and odds. Here is a quick example to what I mean:

Jack and Bob discuss the likelihood that their friend Tom buys the 1963 Sting Ray Corvette for sale at the used car lot down the street. They decide it isn't very likely because Tom suggested it isn't a very good use of money for him and his wife at the time. A few days later Tom's wife comes home from the mall having spent $1200 on shoes, clothes, jewelry and what not that Tom and his wife agreed beforehand that she shouldn't do. This leads Jack to say to Bob, "Odds of Tom buying that car just went waaay up!".

Now, let's first sidestep any actual math related concerns of whether the wife spending the $1200 has any impact on Tom's likelihood of purchasing the Sting Ray and focus on the language used. Jack is indicating the probability of Tom purchasing the car has increased but say the odds increased.

We can see that odds of $$3:1=.25$$ and $$4:1=.20$$ As the odds increased from $3:1$ to $4:1$ the probability decreased. If Jack wanted to indicate that Tom was now more likely to purchase the car,  would it not have been more accurate for Jack to say "The odds of Tom buying that car went waaay down!"?

Is this simply a language issue where people have misused it so much it has almost become hypercorrect in terms of the way we describe it with words? Or, is it just plainly incorrect and stems from the misunderstanding of probability and odds? Or, finally, am I nuts and has everyone else been doing it right?

*Wasn't sure on the best title or what tags were most appropriate. Please update accordingly.*

Comment: I've never heard "the odds went up" as a synonym of "the chances went up" - British native English speaker. I've only heard "the odds of that are practically nil" and "the odds just improved" and similar, or "the chances got better" or "the chances went up" etc.

Answer (score 0):

Actually odds of (in favor of) an event refers to the ratio of the probability of the event occurring to the probability of the event not occurring.  Odds against the event give the flipped ratio.

Thus odds of 3 to 1 of the event is a $.75$ probability of the event occurring; while odds of 4 to 1 of the event is a $.80$ probability of the event occurring.

If the probability of an event occurring is $.25$, the odds are 1 to 3 in favor; or 3 to 1 against.

Comment: I should have specified that I was referring to odds against. That is what is traditionally used in terms of casino games, sports betting, horse racing and so forth (where I'm from, United States).

Comment: I suppose what I am ultimately asking is if have you odds go from $3:1$ to $4:1$ is it correct to say the odds increased? For an odds against situation the probability has decreased. So, according to the above scenario, Jack would need to say the odds went down to reflect an increase in probability.

Comment: I guess you have to be careful to be clear to distinguish between odds in favor and against.  Odds in favor go up as probability goes up; while odds against go up as probability goes down.

Comment: I agree, the distinction seems the defining factor. I suppose there's no right or wrong way with language so long as no baseline is determined since you cannot know for sure whether someone means odds for or against without clarification.